# SQL - NEED LIKE ONLINE OFFLINE STATUS FROM DATETIME

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have one column with DateTime and need the status of each site by SQL select query as I tried below query.
when executing the query getting an error - "'TIMESTAMPDIFF' is not a recognized built-in function name."

```
SELECT co.controllerid,
   co.controllerno,
   co.ControllerName,
   co.SerialNo,
   co.MACAddress,
   c.HBLatestDateTime,
   c.TrnxLatestDateTime,
   'STATUS' AS STAT,
   CASE
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) <= 5 THEN 'online'
        WHEN (TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) > 720
          AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) <= 30) THEN 'idle'
        ELSE 'offline'
   END AS user_status
FROM Controllers AS co
     INNER JOIN Controllersruntime AS c ON c.ControllerID = co.ControllerID
                                       AND co.Markdeleted != 1
WHERE HBLatestDateTime = CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
ORDER BY co.ControllerName ASC;
```

Comment: This question is near impossible to read. The all caps is shouty and not helpful, the code is unformatted. It is unclear what the question is supposed to be as there is no clue to expected and actual results.

Comment: if date = anytime: status = "we're closed go away";

Comment: "Pro" Tip: When writing a program/query/etc language good use of whitespace and linebreaks is a **must**. Putting an entire SQL query on a single line is a sure fire way to make your code unreadable, and impossible to troubleshoot.

Comment: More on topic, what don't you understand about the error? It seems pretty clear: `TIMESTAMPDIFF` isn't a function on SQL Server. According to a Google, it's a MySQL Function. MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products.

Comment: Also, not to pile on, but the logic in the second part of your CASE statement seems to have the operators switched. As written, you're looking for a number greater than 720 and less than or equal to 30. Should probably be the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TIMESTAMPDIFF is a function in MySql, I think you want to use DATEDIFF

```
SELECT co.controllerid,
   co.controllerno,
   co.ControllerName,
   co.SerialNo,
   co.MACAddress,
   c.HBLatestDateTime,
   c.TrnxLatestDateTime,
   'STATUS' AS STAT,
   CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) <= 5 THEN 'online'
        WHEN (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) > 720
          AND DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.HBLatestDateTime, GETDATE()) <= 30) THEN 'idle'
        ELSE 'offline'
   END AS user_status
```

Comment: Works thanks, removed the group by clause. is that possible to online/offline count from the same query or other route